# Filter Start Date with Greather Than or Equal To and End Date that Contains Months as Strings

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

I'm new to working with dates in the tidyverse and I'm attempting to filter by Start_Date that is greater than or equal to 08-MAY-2017, and an End_Date that contains the months of AUG or JUL.

I attempted this with the code below. I first used `lubridate::mdy` on the Start_Date column so I could filter by the date, but left the End_Date column as character so I could use `dplyr::filter` and `stringr::str_detect`.

```
Df <- Df %>% 
        mutate_at(vars(Start_Date),funs(lubridate::mdy)) %>%
        filter(Start_Date >= "08-MAY-2017") %>%
        filter(str_detect(End_Date),"AUG|JUL")
```

This doesn't work, and I'm not sure if it's the best tidyverse method for achieving this, especially since I have two filter lines and two different formats for Start_Date and End_Date.

What is a better way to achieve this using Tidyverse?

Sample Data:

```
ID <- c(455,665,667,398,345,653,999,543)
Start_Date <- c("08-May-2017","03-MAR-2017","04-APR-2017","04-JULY-2017",
                "08-MAY-2017","12-AUG-2017","07-MAY-2017","16-JUL-2017")
End_Date <- c("01-SEP-2017","25-AUG-2017","08-AUG-2017","18-NOV-2017",
              "12-JUL-2017","22-JUL-2017","02-AUG-2017","15-SEP-2017")
Pet <- c("Cat","Dog","Cat","Cat","Turle","Dog","Fish","Rabbit")

Df <- data_frame(ID, Start_Date, End_Date, Pet)
```

Comment: to begin with that second `filter` call should be: `filter(str_detect(End_Date,"AUG|JUL"))`

Comment: There are several typo's in you code. This works for me: `Df %>%  mutate_at(vars(Start_Date), funs(dmy)) %>% filter(Start_Date >= dmy("08-MAY-2017")) %>% filter(str_detect(End_Date,"AUG|JUL"))`. The typo's are: (1) use `dmy` instead of `mdy` & (2) the brackets for `str_detect` were in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mutate_at step didn't seem to work, but you just need to convert to date format initially, and then apply filtering step (which you can do in one step). You could make it more concise if you can remember the default format `as.Date` uses (I can never remember)

```
Df %>% 
    # convert to date format
    mutate_at(vars(Start_Date, End_Date),function(x) as.Date(x, format="%d-%b-%Y")) %>%
    # apply start and end filter criteria (can do in single filter call)
    filter(Start_Date >= as.Date("08-05-2017", format="%d-%m-%Y"),
           End_Date %in% as.Date("01-07-2017", format="%d-%m-%Y"):as.Date("31-08-2017", format="%d-%m-%Y"))
```

EDIT: I reminded myself and it wants %Y-%m-%d format:

```
Df %>% 
    # convert to date format
    mutate_at(vars(Start_Date, End_Date),function(x) as.Date(x, format="%d-%b-%Y")) %>%
    # apply start and end filter criteria (can do in single filter call)
    filter(Start_Date >= as.Date("2017-05-08"),
           End_Date %in% as.Date("2017-07-01"):as.Date("2017-08-31"))
```